# Laravel stream return string instead of file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to download a file created in stream to not have to write it in the disk. Here is what I do :

```
$response = new StreamedResponse(function() use ($csv_data) {
  // Open output stream
  $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
  foreach ($csv_data as $row) {
    fputcsv($handle, $row);
  }
  fclose($handle);

}, 200, [
  'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
  'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="legend.csv"',
]);


return $response;
```

Here is a screen of what I have in the network tab of chrome :
[image]

I use the StreamedResponse according to the documentation but it's returning me the string of the values of my csvfile ("value1","value2", ...) but not the csvfile itself.

This method is called by an angular app.

What I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT :**

I try to make with a form :

```
        var form = angular.element('<form></form>');
        form.attr('action', 'http://myUrl/export-csv');
        form.attr('method', 'POST');
        var input = angular.element('<input></input>');
        input.attr('type', 'hidden');
        input.attr('name', 'data');
        input.attr('value', finalData);
        form.append(input);
        angular.element(document).find('body').append(form);
        form.submit().remove();
```

This will maybe works but I have some strange things, first the form redirect to the URL and not make a post request to it, when he redirect I have an ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE (but the url exist and the data is good => I test with postman and it works)

Comment: Apparently you need a [`Content-Disposition`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files) header.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about the returned response? Maybe you can attach a screenshot or something to clearly spot what you want to point out.

Comment: Jerodev I try with this header but same result, alariva I add a screen

Comment: What exactly are you expecting here?  It seems your response is valid.  Are you using an AJAX request or something?

Comment: I need that the response is a downloaded file, here I have just a text in the network tab.

Comment: Well, don't perform the request in AJAX if you want a download to occur..

Comment: I'm doing a post request, I use an angular app for the front and laravel for the backend, what can I do if I want to download ? ..

Comment: Not sure why you'd do a post request for a download, doesn't really fit into  the definition of a POST, as POST is meant for creating/storing resources not retrieving them.  AJAX requests aren't meant for downloading, they are meant for background requests.  Do a normal form submission and it should work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

Comment: I edit with a try of your solution